# How to give a change the value of a variable when radio button is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, checked

I am currently trying to make a calculator using javascript and I have been able to add the what the user will input into textboxes and I am trying to change the value of a variable when a radio is checked. Is there any way to change the value of the variable when the ratio is checked?

Thanks in advance

```
let firstInput = document.querySelector('#firstInput');
let secondInput = document.querySelector('#secondInput');
let thirdInput = document.querySelector('#thirdInput');

let btnAdd = document.querySelector('button');
let result = document.querySelector('h1');

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () =>{
  let total = parseFloat(firstInput.value) + parseFloat(secondInput.value) + 
parseFloat(thirdInput.value) + parseInt(genderReflection);
  result.innerText = total.toFixed(3);    
});

window.onload = function(){
  var genderReflection  = {
    price: 5
  }
  var maleRelaxation  = document.getElementById('Male');
  Male.addEventListener('click' ,function(){
    genderReflection.price  +=  parseFloat(maleRelaxation.value)
  })
}


<input type="number" id="firstInput">
<div id="calculator">
  <input type="radio" id="Male" name="gender" value="5">
  <label for="Male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" id="Female" name="gender" value="-161">
  <label for="Female">Female</label>
</div>

<input type="number" id="secondInput">
<input type="number" id="thirdInput">
<button>ADD</button>
<h1>result</h1>
```

Comment: put the code in function that does the calculation. Put a change event on the radio buttons. Call the function for that and the button click...

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `onClick="function_name(amount)"` onto the inputs.
Where function name would add the variable to a (globally declared) list.
From there, the logic is yours.

##### Edit

Ofcourse, adding an eventlistener and getting the attribute as specified in comment above would probably be better. Saves typing. ;)

Answer (score 0):

two errors:

```
1)place all the js code inside window.onload
2)to get the value out of genderReflection use generReflection.price
```

```js
window.onload = function(){
let firstInput = document.querySelector('#firstInput');
let secondInput = document.querySelector('#secondInput');
let thirdInput = document.querySelector('#thirdInput');

let btnAdd = document.querySelector('button');
let result = document.querySelector('h1');

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () =>{
  let total = parseFloat(firstInput.value) + parseFloat(secondInput.value) + 
parseFloat(thirdInput.value) + parseInt(genderReflection.price);

  result.innerText = total.toFixed(3);    
});

  var genderReflection  = {
    price: 5
  }
  var maleRelaxation  = document.getElementById('Male');
  Male.addEventListener('click' ,function(){
    genderReflection.price  +=  parseFloat(maleRelaxation.value)
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="firstInput">
<div id="calculator">
  <input type="radio" id="Male" name="gender" value="15">
  <label for="Male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" id="Female" name="gender" value="-161">
  <label for="Female">Female</label>
</div>

<input type="number" id="secondInput">
<input type="number" id="thirdInput">
<button>ADD</button>
<h1>result</h1>
```